# Alter login form in block by id

Tags: forms, hooks

I have a small problem on D7, I need to alter the login form inside block (add class to inputs, placeholder and submit button text, custom pass reset and login links) im using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter. I don't need to use custom module.

block id = block-user-login, form id = user_login_block

My theme.php code

```
function themename_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

    $form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Username' );
    $form['pass']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Password' );

   // custom register link
    $form['actions']['signup'] = array(
        '#markup' => l(t('Register'), 'user/register', array(
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'top-user-block-link register',
                'title' => t('Create a new user account.')
            )
        )),
    );

    // custom reset password link
    $form['actions']['request_password'] = array(
        '#markup' => l(t('Forgot my password'), 'user/password', array(
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'top-user-block-link new-password',
                'title' => t('Request new password.'),
            )
        )),
    );
}
```

Links for password reset and login links renders fine, but i can't make the placeholders or class add to work.

i've tried to use

```
function theme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id === 'user_login_block') {
$form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Username' );
    $form['pass']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Password' );
  }
}
```

but i works only on /login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Username' );
$form['pass']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Password' );
```

Both the code are working. If you can't see your changes or placeholder.

Please try with `var_dump($form)`. You will find `$form_id` and all other fields of the form. just check your debug (array) ordering and make sure that order is same as in your `form_alter()` function.

Comment: var_dump($form) do the job, it was some custom login form generated form module. Simply i was calling bad id.

Comment: Now, Working? Or need help ?

Comment: Yes, work perfect ! :) thx !

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, you need `$form['account']['name']['#attributes']`.